# Akka remote `system.shutdown()` leads to EndpointDisassociatedException?

Tags: xml, akka

I have simple Client and Server setup and at some point after sending all the asynchronous requests and upon the Server acknowledging it, the Client invokes `system.shutdown()`. This leads the Server to `akka.remote.EndpointDisassociatedException` and a bunch of log errors as shown below. I'm not happy with a bunch of errors in my logs so I would like to know what's causing all this. The outcome of the system as a whole works successfully, the error only shows at the point where the Client shutdown.

```
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 ERROR EndpointWriter - AssociationError [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] <- [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]: Error [Disassociated] [
akka.remote.EndpointDisassociatedException: Disassociated
]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 DEBUG EndpointWriter - Disassociated [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] <- [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 ERROR EndpointWriter - AssociationError [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.224.65:2552
]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 DEBUG EndpointWriter - Disassociated [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 ERROR EndpointWriter - AssociationError [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.224.65:2552
]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 DEBUG EndpointWriter - Disassociated [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 ERROR EndpointWriter - AssociationError [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.224.65:2552
]
28.Jun.2013-10:13:01 DEBUG EndpointWriter - Disassociated [akka.tcp://MapReduceApp@127.0.0.1:2552] -> [akka.tcp://WordCountClientApp@192.168.224.65:2552]
```

UPDATE: I'm using Akka version 2.2.0-RC1 and the Scala version is 2.10.0 but it also happens with Scala version 2.10.1. I use Maven and the software versions are:

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.10.0</scala.version>
    <akka.version>2.2.0-RC1</akka.version>
    <scalatest.version>2.0.M6-SNAP16</scalatest.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
    <guava.version>14.0.1</guava.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

and the corresponding dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-kernel_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-agent_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-zeromq_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You're not providing which version you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this logging with configuration property:
`akka.remote.log-remote-lifecycle-events=off`

Comment: Thank you! You imply then that this is not an error but rather information? why is it logged as an error?

Comment: Tested and works, I no longer get any Error logs after using your suggested configuration solution.